# ng serve command causes error "Cannot find name 'describe' (or 'beforeEach', 'it', 'expect', etc.)"

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to run a Karma/Jasmine unit test on a library we've built (this is Angular version 8). The unit test runs fine (using "ng test"), but when I try to compile (ng build), I get the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha` and then add `jest` or `mocha` to the types field in your tsconfig.
```

I get this same error for 'beforeEach', 'it', 'expect', and 'describe'.

I have tried:

- Reinstalling all node_module files.
- Importing 'jasmine' in the spec.ts file.
- Installing @types/jest and @types/mocha as the error message instructed.
- Adding both of these, as well as a few other installed modules, to the "types" list in the tsconfig.json (see file at the end of the post).
- Verifying that the index.d.ts file in the node_modules@types\jasmine contains the definitions for the methods I'm receiving errors for.

Just the basic, auto-generated test file causes compilation errors:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Here's the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node",
      "jasmine",
      "jasminewd2",
      "mocha"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Just for reference, I'm running TypeScript 3.5.3, Karma 4.1.0, and Jasmine 3.4.0.

Comment: Which versions are each of your types? You could be using an out of date version. Also, you don't need jest/mocha if you're not using those types. The error was giving you a suggestion. The Describe is a function that belongs to jasmine already.

Comment: Node is 8.9.4, Jasmine is 3.4.0, and jasminewd2 is 2.0.3.

Comment: Just checked, and Node is out of date by a fair amount of versions. I'll try updating that and report on how it worked.

Comment: No dice. Still gives the same errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to reproduce this error it to comment out one line in your `src/tsconfig.app.json` file.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    // "**/*.spec.ts" <-- commenting this out loads your spec, which isn't what you want for npm start
  ]
}
```

The other possibility is that you have misnamed a spec file so that this filter doesn't exclude it, or you've written tests in an actual `.ts` file.

Comment: It turned out to be a faulty spec file. Thanks for the response!